# Delete all records that are not the latest

Tags: stored-procedures, duplicates, sql-server-2014, sql-delete

I have a table that deliberately has duplicates in it. In this instance the things that will be duplicated are a deviceId, and the datetime. Sometimes the customer updates their data. The table has three columns, deviceId, datetime and value (there is an incremental primary key). Sometimes when the customer re-evaluates their data, they notice that the value is incorrect, they then update it and send the data for re-processing. As a consequence, i need to be able to delete records that are not the very latest records. I cant do it by datetime, as this will also be duplicated in some cases and I cant truncate the staging table.

To delete the dupes I have the following:

```
;WITH DupeData AS (
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY tblMeterData_Id,fldDateTime, fldValue, [fldBatchId],[fldProcessed] ORDER BY fldDateTime) AS ROW
FROM [Stage.tblMeterData])
DELETE FROM DupeData 
WHERE ROW > 1
```

The problem with this, is it seems to delete a random duplicate.

I want to keep the latest record that is in the staging area and delete any others that are not the latest record. I can then update the relevant row with the new value, with the latest data, when I take it from staging into prod.

Comment: is any primary  or unique key on the table?
`DELETE FROM DupeData 
where id in 
(select id from (
SELECT id, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY tblMeterData_Id,fldDateTime, fldValue, [fldBatchId],[fldProcessed] ORDER BY fldDateTime) AS ROW
FROM [Stage.tblMeterData])
) q
where q.row > 1)`

Comment: Only the incremental Id that I used to send the table up.

Comment: I think the penny just dropped!

Comment: ok... move it into answer then

Answer (score 0, accepted):

is any primary or unique key on the table? 
if there's unique id - the easiest way below
not sure about performance but should work ok on small amounts

```
DELETE FROM DupeData 
where id in 
(select id from 
( SELECT id, 
  ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY tblMeterData_Id,fldDateTime, fldValue, [fldBatchId],[fldProcessed] ORDER BY fldDateTime) AS ROW 
FROM [Stage.tblMeterData]) 
) q
 where q.row > 1)
```

Comment: I'm trying that and no records are effected, even though i know I have four duplicates for each device Id. I have tried fiddling around with it and it doesn't find any dupes to delete.

Comment: DELETE FROM [Stage.tblMeterData] 
 WHERE ID IN
 (
  SELECT ID FROM 
  ( 
   SELECT ID, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY tblMeterData_Id,fldDateTime ORDER BY fldDateTime DESC) AS ROW 
   FROM [Stage.tblMeterData]
  ) AS q 
  WHERE q.ROW > 1
 )